# Suppress most elements of an Array but one from JSON Response in Angular 2

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have a JSON response from a Server as follows:
**HTTP GET**:

```
{
    searchType: "search_1",
    overview: [
                "Bed",
                "BedSheets",
                "BedLinen",
                 ..
              ]
}
```

Depending on the keyword, the Array `overview` varies.

I store every searched keyword and its response in an Array called `Output` as follows:

```
[
    {kw: keyword1, resp: {aboveMentioned JSON response},
    {kw: keyword2, resp: {other JSON response with varying elements in `overview` array}
]
```

in my `component.html` file, I want to display the entries within a `overview` array as *Buttons*.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let eachOutput of Output">
    <div *ngFor="let each of eachOutput.resp.overview">
      <button *ngIf="eachOutput.resp.overview.length >=1">{{each}}</button>
    </div> <!-- TRY TO SHOW JUST THE FIRST ELEMENT but how? -->
    <!--- Try to display the other buttons with some option like 'More'
      next to the first button -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Currently, there are some keywords where the elements of array are in a large quantity but I would like to show only the `overview[0]` as a button and something like a text like `More Options` which upon click shows the other elements of `overview`.

what is the proper use of `ngFor` and `ngIf` here? I have heard that `hidden` CSS attribute is discouraged with Angular 2.

Comment: Heard from where?

Comment: @nitind http://angularjs.blogspot.de/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the index within the `*ngFor` loops to identify the first element. With an array of booleans you can store the state of which buttons should be viewed.

#### component.ts (implements OnInit)

```
(...)
@Input() Output: any[] = [];
showMore: boolean[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.showMore = new Array(this.Output.length);
  this.showMore.fill(false);
}
(...)
```

#### component.html

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let eachOutput of Output; let outerIndex = index">
    <div *ngFor="let each of eachOutput.resp.overview; let index = index">
      <button *ngIf="index === 0 || showMore[outerIndex]">{{each}}</button>
    </div>
    <button *ngIf="eachOutput.resp.overview.length > 1" 
      (click)="showMore[outerIndex]=!showMore[outerIndex]">
        {{showMore[outerIndex] ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}} more Buttons
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The only thing that might be a problem is the `{{showMore[outerIndex] ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}}`. My button keeps using 'Show' everytime not the 'Hide' text.

Comment: I tried it in a plunker and it seemed to worked. https://plnkr.co/edit/b28zkSGUWHlkt6lzq6QZ?p=preview

Maybe there is a problem with ChangeDetection in your case? You could move the inner loop and its show more button to a second component and therewith get rid of the array of booleans. In my opinion that would be more clean and might solve your problem.

Comment: Ah ! Had a small typo in the HTML file. that was the reason! thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that. :) If it solved your problem, I'd be happy if you'd accept my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to keep any remotely complex logic out of my templates, so I would take a different approach - split your response objects into the first *primary* object, and then an array of the remaining *secondary* objects, that you display if a flag value is true.

This makes your template easy to code - and more importantly (in my opinion), easy to read and understand for anyone editing your code.

This might look something like:

```
[
 {kw: keyword1, response: {primaryResponse: 'Bed', secondaryItems: {bedlinen, pillows}},
 {kw: keyword2, response: {primaryResponse: 'Door', secondaryItems: {window, handle}}
]

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let eachOutput of Output">
    <button *ngIf="eachOutput.response.primaryResponse">
      {{eachOutput.response.primaryResponse}}</button>

    <button (click)="ToggleSecondaryItems()">More</button>

    <div *ngIf="showSecondaryItems">
      <div *ngFor="let each of eachOutput.response.secondaryItems">
        <button *ngIf="each.overview.length > 0">{{each}}</button>
      </div>
    <//div>    
  </li>
</ul>
```

*I've not tested this, so there may be some errors in the code - but I hope it shows the basic idea.

Comment: Thanks this is definitely worth thinking about. I will get back to this soon.